# Linear Transformations, Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation, linear-transformations

Let T:P3→P3 be the linear transformation such that $T(−2x^2)= −2x^2 − 2x$, $T(0.5x + 2)= 3x^2 + 4x−2$, and $T(2x^2 − 1)= 2x + 1$. 
Find $T(1), T(x), T(x^2)$, and $T(ax^2 + bx + c)$, where a, b, and c are arbitrary real numbers.

I understand how to find $T(x^2)$ where you just divide the given $T(-2x^2)$ by $-2$ to get $T(x^2) = x^2 + x$.

I'm not sure sure how to proceed in calculating the other transformation functions. Please list as many of the steps as possible in solving for the three other functions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write $1=-(-2x^2)-(2x^2-1), x=2(0.5x+2)-4$, so 
$$T(1)=T(-(-2x^2)-(2x^2-1))=-T(-2x^2)-T(2x^2-1)=2x^2-1$$
$$T(x)=T(2(0.5x+2)-4)=2T(0.5x+2)-4T(1)=-2x^2+8x$$
Then we get 
$$T(ax^2+bx+c)=a(x^2+x)+b(-2x^2+8x)+c(2x^2-1)$$
$$=(a-2b+2c)x^2+(a+8b)x-c$$

Comment: Oh! so you're making linear combinations of the portions inside the the parenthesis to equate to the unknown. That's such a more helpful way of looking at these kind of problems. Thank you.